# How to draw a cylinder along x-axis using three js?

Tags: three.js

The default axis of the cylinder is y-axis, forms a verticle cylinder. I need to draw a horizontal cylinder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.rotateZ()` method of your cylinder geometry:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 5, 10);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));

var geom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1, 1, 7, 16, 1);
geom.rotateZ(-Math.PI * 0.5); // rotate 90 degrees clockwise around z-axis

var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "aqua",
  wireframe: true
}));
scene.add(cylinder);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```